# EF Core: Invalid column name 'companyId1'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have trouble understanding why a EF generated SELECT clause contains the primary key twice, the second one is postfixed with '1'.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [entity.WebAdminCompanyUser].[CompanyId], [entity.WebAdminCompanyUser].[AspNetUserId], [entity.WebAdminCompanyUser].[CompanyId1]
FROM [SafeProtect].[WebAdminCompanyUser] AS [entity.WebAdminCompanyUser]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [entity1].[AspNetUserId]
    FROM [SafeProtect].[WebAdminUser] AS [entity1]
    WHERE ([entity1].[RowEnabled] = 1) AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [SafeProtect].[WebAdminCompanyUser] AS [companyUser1]
        WHERE ([companyUser1].[CompanyId] = @__companyId_0) AND ([entity1].[AspNetUserId] = [companyUser1].[AspNetUserId]))
) AS [t0] ON [entity.WebAdminCompanyUser].[AspNetUserId] = [t0].[AspNetUserId]
ORDER BY [t0].[AspNetUserId]',N'@__companyId_0 int',@__companyId_0=1
```

It fails with **Invalid column name 'CompanyId1'**.

Following are the entities and the corresponding configurations (fluent API):

**WebAdminCompanyUser**:

```
public partial class WebAdminCompanyUser : ITrackable, IMergeable
{
    public WebAdminCompanyUser()
    {
        AdditionalInit();
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TrackingState TrackingState { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<string> ModifiedProperties { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Guid EntityIdentifier { get; set; }

    partial void AdditionalInit();
}
```

}

Configuration:

```
builder.Entity<WebAdminCompanyUser>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable(name: "WebAdminCompanyUser", schema: SqlSchema.SafeProtect);
    entity.HasKey("CompanyId", "AspNetUserId");

    entity
       .HasOne(d => d.Company)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
       .IsRequired();
});
```

**WebAdminUser**:

```
public partial class WebAdminUser : IdentityUser<int>, IAuditInfo, IRowDisableableWithDateTime, ITrackable, IMergeable
{
    public WebAdminUser()
    {
        WebAdminCompanyUser = new HashSet<WebAdminCompanyUser>();
        WebAdminUserRole = new HashSet<WebAdminUserRole>();
        WebAdminUserClaim = new HashSet<WebAdminUserClaim>();
        WebAdminUserLogin = new HashSet<WebAdminUserLogin>();

        AdditionalInit();
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public bool RowEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DisabledOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WebAdminCompanyUser> WebAdminCompanyUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WebAdminUserRole> WebAdminUserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WebAdminUserClaim> WebAdminUserClaim { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WebAdminUserLogin> WebAdminUserLogin { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TrackingState TrackingState { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<string> ModifiedProperties { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Guid EntityIdentifier { get; set; }

    partial void AdditionalInit();
}
```

Configuration:

```
    builder.Entity<WebAdminUser>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable(name: "WebAdminUser", schema: SqlSchema.SafeProtect);
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("AspNetUserId");

        // authorize multiple user name
        entity.HasIndex((p) => new { p.UserName }).IsUnique(false);

        entity
              .HasMany(user => user.WebAdminUserClaim)
              .WithOne()
              .HasForeignKey(userClaims => userClaims.UserId)
              .IsRequired();

        entity
            .HasMany(user => user.WebAdminUserLogin)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(userLogin => userLogin.UserId)
            .IsRequired();

        entity
            .HasMany(user => user.WebAdminUserRole)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.UserId)
            .IsRequired();

        entity
             .HasMany(user => user.WebAdminCompanyUser)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey(companyUser => companyUser.AspNetUserId)
             .IsRequired();
    });
```

EF query:

```
IQueryable<WebAdminUser> query =
                    from WebAdminUser user WebAdminUserRepository.All()
                        .Include(user => user.WebAdminUserRole)
                            .ThenInclude(userRole => userRole.AspNetRole)
                        .Include(user => user.WebAdminCompanyUser)
                    where user.WebAdminCompanyUser.Any(companyUser => companyUser.CompanyId == companyId)
                    select user;

                return query.ToList();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: With `[ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId))]` on `Company` property would probably do the same result, but maybe it is worth trying out.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik confirmed. Same result.

Comment: CompanyId is defined as an integer.  Is any place in code or database using a string for the ID?  May be the local variable companyId is defined as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually happens when you have improperly mapped relationship by leaving some navigation property out of fluent configuration.

Remember that each navigation property (collection or reference) represents a relationship. If you fluently configure relationships and use `HasOne` / `HasMany` / `WithOne` / `WithMany` w/o passing the navigation property, you are telling EF that the relationship *has no navigation property* for the corresponding end. But if you actually *do have* navigation property, EF will map it to a *separate* relationship with default FK column name. If the default property/column name is already used, EF will append index to it until it gets unique.

In your case, the `WebAdminUser` class and configuration you've shown are irrelevant. The invalid column name `CompanyId1` indicates that the problem is with `Company` class which you haven't shown, and the `WithMany()` call here

```
   .HasOne(d => d.Company)
   .WithMany() // <--
```

Most likely your `Company` class has collection navigation property to `WebAdminCompanyUser`, something like this (`virtual` and the name of the property doesn't matter):

```
public virtual ICollection<WebAdminCompanyUser> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
```

then you need to change the above `.WithMany()` call with something like

```
.WithMany(c => c.CompanyUsers)
```

and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much. This took me hours to figure out. After reading your comment and explicitly adding the .WithOne(c => c.Parent) it worked. They DO NOT say this in the EF docs! Grrr